# Is it possible to chain nested commands within QAxObject?

Tags: qt, qaxobject

I am wondering if is it possible to do some chaining of commands/actions inside the QAxObject.

For example to change the Cell color in Excel, I need to do something like this:

```
QAxObject* cell = sheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)",row,col));
QAxObject* interior = cell->querySubObject("Interior"));
interior->setProperty("Color",color);
```

So I am wondering if is it possible something like this:

```
QAxObject* cell = sheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)",row,col));
cell->setProperty("Interior.Color"),color);
```

Or better:

```
cell.Interior.Color = color;
```